# PHP preg_match to get function-like string

Tags: php, regex

if I have a string like 'foo(bar)', with the following code i can *almost* parse it the way i want:

```
$results = array();
preg_match( "/\w*(?=(\(.*\))?)/", 'foo(bar)', &$results );
print_r($results);

/*    
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => (bar)
)
*/
```

How can I modify the regex to have `bar` instead of `(bar)`? Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using look ahead? Normally `/(\w+)\((\w+)\)/` would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'/\w*(?=(?:\((.*)\))?)/'
```